# How is the Size of the struct calculated correctly?

Tags: c, structure

What would be the size of MyStruct on windows 7 , 64 bit  ?

```
    typedef struct MyStruct_tag
   {
       char        c;
       double      d;
       int         s;
    } MyStruct;
```

My answer:

```
1 (Char) + 7 (Padding) + 8 (double) + 4 (int) = 20 bytes
```

But the answer is coming out 24 bytes. What is going on ?

Comment: 4 padding bits after last member.

Comment: @haccks why ? any advantage ?

Comment: Read the answer given below and the answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 4):

The final `int` is likely followed by 4 bytes of padding so that the alignment of the `double` in the next similar struct in an array will be properly aligned.

But ultimately, padding is implementation-defined.  Trying to reason about or predict it isn't useful.  The compiler should take care of it for you.  If it doesn't, strongly reconsider what you're doing.

Comment: You can use `__attribute__((packed))` to specify that you don't wants the struct attributes to be aligned (not the best practice).

Answer (score 2):

It's for ``alignment''. Many processors can't access 2- and 4-byte quantities (e.g. ints and long ints) if they're crammed in every-which-way.

Suppose you have this structure:

```
struct  {
    char a[3];
    short int b;
    long int c;
    char d[3];
    };
```

Now, you might think that it ought to be possible to pack this structure into memory like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           |   b   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   b   |           c           |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   c   |           d           |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

But it's much, much easier on the processor if the compiler arranges it like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       b       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|               c               |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           d           |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

In the `packed'' version, notice how it's at least a little bit hard for you and me to see how the b and c fields wrap around? In a nutshell, it's hard for the processor, too. Therefore, most compilers will`pad'' the structure (as if with extra, invisible fields) like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           | pad1  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       b       |     pad2      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|               c               |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           d           | pad3  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

*Courtesy - Steve Summit*

Comment: In the maps above are you assuming that int is 2 byte?